# Resources for Smartphone Security

Tags: security, mobile-devices

My organization is currently working on improving our data and network security due to increasing HIPAA laws and a general need to get a better grasp on controlling our health related information.  We are a non-profit working with people with developmental disabilities so we handle a lot of medical related information.

One area that has been identified as a risk is our use of smartphones, specifically at this time Windows Mobile 6.1 devices from T-Mobile.

We do not utilize the VPNs on the phones so there isn't any way they can access our databases or file servers (username/password for VPNs is not the domain logons).  What would be exposed however is the particular user's email account since you could extract out the username/password and access the email either on the device or on our web email (Exchange 2003) which could contain HIPAA protected confidential information about clients and services and this would be an incident that would have to be reported.

What resources or ideas would help us secure these devices?  I'm not worried about data interception (using SSL) but more about physical theft or loss of the device.  Are there websites that I just have not found with guidelines and suggestions or particualar products that would help protect us?

I also don't want to limit the discussion to windows Mobile either.  I myself am looking at an android 2.0 device and there is always the eventual possibility we could get pushed to enable the VPNs.

I know this is a subject that likely won't have any particular correct answer and it is something we should all be aware of since there devices are sitting outside of our immediate control most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [googling](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Security-Mobile-Device-Era.html) for mobile security and [hipaa](http://www.scmagazineus.com/five-steps-to-securing-mobile-data-for-hipaa-compliance/article/112019/) and how it relates to Windows Mobile [specifically](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:RVzANPF1Sb4J:download.microsoft.com/download/6/0/3/60362db7-837d-4e15-86df-1e278ff0c2ed/Windows%2520Mobile%2520and%2520HIPAA.pdf+hippa+%2Bmobile+device&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESivMdO6mQSqT4TncVB00ngpnggmCMRL9U7mSw7lY64KLUfdoLo2wqk4PqUgZia7Y3qcstCoJblRrrPwaLTIMzKZHpyQ8CM7IR99h8iK_1gZN3ZNfWI7qRN0hYJnKfTjOy3GqNAu&sig=AHIEtbR150lYPTHx-fI3ESgI25ge6xZ1wg), you should also look into the [remote wipe](http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2005/07/07/407416.aspx) capabilities of Exchange 2003.

Comment: The remote wipe is nice, I thought that was only a feature of exchange 2007.  Problem I'm seeing after testing it is it prompts the user to take effect.  I will need to look into how to make it seamless, otherwise information on the device is still exposed.